# How to correctly identify when an SVG path element has holes in it

Tags: svg

I am building an SVG renderer for my project, the issue I am having at the moment is identifying when a path contains many shapes Vs when it contains a single shape but with subsequent shapes representing holes ( many shapes / holes being represented be M/m Z/z groupings). I am also unsure if groups of paths  can represent a shape with holes in too. Is there a set of rules I can follow to easily acertain how to render the shape?

I have seen instances of a single path with many shapes in and a single path with one shape and many holes. The browsers draw both types properly so there must be some logic behind the interpretation.

Comment: https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#WindingRule

Comment: Thanks, so the default rule is non-zero. I take it there are no rules around winding order? ie the outer shape could be either CW or CCW.